# Insert an HTML Object element in Webbrowser's document

Tags: dom, .net-4.0

In a `Webbrowser` control there is a webpage (the document). I know how to insert any HTML element into the body.

The problem is, how can I insert an `<object>` along with its `<param>`? I must keep the existing document, so I wouldn't use `Webbrowser1.Document.Write()`.

```
Dim player As HtmlElement = Webbrowser1.Document.CreateElement("object")
player.SetAttribute("width", "640")
player.SetAttribute("height", "480")

Dim param As HtmlElement = Webbrowser1.Document.CreateElement("param")
param.SetAttribute("name", "movie")
param.SetAttribute("value", "http://foo.bar.com/player.swf")

player.AppendChild(param) '<== throws an exception

Webbrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(player)
```

Thrown exception: *"Value is not among the set of valid lookup values"* (I guess, because I'm using french version of VS2010, which gives me *"La valeur n'est pas comprise dans la plage attendue."*)

**WORKAROUND**

Finally I could append an `<object>` element using `Navigate()` method with Javascript URI. It's a bit ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realized my answer was exactly what you were doing. Oops.

The MSDN documentation shows a lot of methods for the [object Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535859%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but it doesn't specify `appendChild`. The `appendChild` method documentation specifies that it is a part of a bunch of objects, but not object.  [`applyElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536341%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) looks like it might work.

Also, the [`insertAdjacentHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536452%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method and [`innerHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) parameter are valid on object Objects, and may be helpful.

---

<strike>Hrm - I'm not familiar with .net, but I have done something similar in Javascript.  Chrome seems to produce the correct document setup with the following:</strike>

```
<script>
  var newObj=document.createElement( "object" );
    newObj.setAttribute( 'width', '640' );
    newObj.setAttribute( 'height', '480' );
    newObj.setAttribute( 'data', 'http://ozdoctorwebsite.com/test-4938161.gif' );

  var newParam=document.createElement( "param" );
    newParam.setAttribute( 'name', 'test' );

  newObj.appendChild( newParam );
  document.body.appendChild( newObj );
</script>
```

Basically - append your param element to the player and append the player to the document.body.

Comment: The thrown exception stack trace includes `InsertAdjacentElement` method, so I think it is used internally. Anyway, using it directly throws the same exception. I didn't find `ApplyElement` method in .NET 4, and `InnerHTML` property throws another exception.